# HAL_SPI_Transmit does not send the bit pattern expected way

Tags: stm32, c, nucleo, hal

As a beginner, to test HAL_SPI_Transmit function for [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0365-stm32f302xbcde-and-stm32f302x68-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) Nucleo board, I wanted to send 0b10101010 on MOSI line and observe it on scope. But I don't see that bit pattern on scope, instead I see the following:

[image]

I use SPI3 and the following auto generated pinouts for SPI:

[image]

And here is auto generated clock and SPI3 settings:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL16;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief SPI3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 1 */
  /* SPI3 parameter configuration*/
  hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
  hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi3.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;
  hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi3.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi3.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 2 */

}
```

And finally in the while loop I try to send the 8-bit as follows:

```
  uint8_t outputBuffer = 0b10101010;

  while (1)
  {
      HAL_Delay(1);
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi3, &outputBuffer, 1, 1);
  }
```

What could be the reason the scope output is different then the bit pattern I send?

Comment: It looks inverted.....

Comment: I think it looks just as expected. Is it that the MOSI is idling high that confuses you?

Comment: Can you read the SCK signal with a different channel?

Comment: Send some other byte, which looks less symmetrical. For instance, 0xF0 (0b11110000). Just experiment with it a little more with different characters. For now, it doesn't look suspicious. And yeah, better have clock signal on the scope too so that you see how clock correlates with data and when/at what positions of the waveform the stuff will be read on the slave side. Remember, that you have "MSB First"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't see that bit pattern on scope

Yes you do. Or you don't. Since MOSI idles high, we can't really tell if the scope pattern is 0x55 or 0xAA without seeing the clock at the same time. You can't really troubleshoot SPI without 2 probes at once. (I recommend 2 channel scope for MOSI + SCLK with a 3rd extern trigger probe for /SS.)

If the first clock edge lies before the MOSI falling edge and that corresponds with your CPOL/CPHA setting, then everything is working as intended.